# Spring request response send null value

Tags: java, spring

Hi i built a backend with Spring and was thinking about whats the best solution in this case:

I normally respond a request with a pojo with some data. But when the requesting user is not authorized i respond with null, what seems to be a ugly way.

I thought it  could be the better way, to return a response entity http unauthorized but the return type is the data pojo.

Maybe i have to change my security config and must! filter the users before the controller method is called?

Comment: Do you have auth annotations on your controllers?

Comment: No only restcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You should validate the request before calling the Controllers by creating Interceptor.You can use JWT tokens for validations.If the user is unauthorised application should respond with Unauthorised.

Comment: Ok i think i have to review the security config. Actually it permits all requests. I use jwt tokens, but have to call userservice to check authorization in the controller.

Comment: ok, you can implement a customized class from HandlerInterceptor. You can override preHandle method for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use spring security basic authorization

http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-basic-authentication/